# How can I get parameter from Bloc without using Blocprovider/Bloccomsumer...?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have defined a bloc named "AppBloc" that manage user login/logout activity of user:

```
class AppBloc extends Bloc<AppEvent, AppState> {
  AppBloc()
      : super(
          const AppStateLoggedOut(
            isLoading: false,
          ),
        ) {

    on<AppEventGoToRegistration>((event, emit) {
      emit(
        const AppStateIsInRegistrationView(
          isLoading: false,
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

In that AppBloc, I want to define `user` variable: `User user` and want to get that variable from another screen by call `AppBloc().User` . But I can not do the constructor for `AppBloc()` .

try: Add variable: `User user` to constructor of AppBloc

UPDATE:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BlocProvider.of` to get the registered bloc in the `context`.

```
BlocProvider.of<AppBloc>(context).state
```